# How differentiate HTTP Request Method In python azure function?

Tags: python, azure-functions

I wrote a python azure function.init.py is

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    print("------------------")
    #print(func.HttpMethod) not working
    return func.HttpResponse( status_code=200)
```

is there any way to distinguish the post and get call?

I know how to get in c# .using System.Net.Http.

Comment: have you tried the ```method``` property on the HttpRequest object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.httprequest?view=azure-python, ```req.method```?

Comment: NO.i tried  req.HttpMethod

Comment: this is working req.method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `mrxra` mentioned in the comments, you can use `req.method` to get the http call is a `get` request or a `post` request.